# Magento 2 Admin 404 Error

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, magento

I just manually installed Magento2 CE on Ubuntu server 18.04 with LAMP via composer, the install went ok and all checks were on green however the link given after installation to access the magento admin page is giving error 404.

To resolve this a few people say it should work by changing from the config:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

From:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

but is still not working, another tutorials also say to change the file `pub/.htaccess` to magento root folder which I'm guessing it would be located default on:  `/var/www/html/magento`

However I'm new to Ubuntu commands and I'm unable to find any suggestions of how to do this, would it work with this?

```
sudo mv /var/www/html/magento/pub/.htaccess /var/www/html/magento
```

If, I tried it and is not working, any suggestions?? or anyone here who have fixed this issue before??

Answer (score 0):

You should check the specific VirtualHost to find what is the document root directory, and then set the `AllowOverride` directive for that directory. For example:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/magento/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Where `/var/www/html/magento` is the document root directory of your domain name. You should also make sure that a [.htaccess](https://github.com/emizentech/magento2/blob/master/.htaccess.sample) file is created in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

If the installation is completely done and Magento admin page is giving error 404, I think this is due to the actual Magento path not set in core_config_data table of database you have created for this.

So please check these two paths values is valid Magento path or not, if not please change it

```
web/unsecure/base_url = http://localhost/training/Magento2.1.7/
web/secure/base_url = https://localhost/training/Magento2.1.7/
```

where *training/Magento2.1.7* is my Magento path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes it happened when we installed Magento 2 and 404 error occured. This error may be one of these:

Error after installing/upgrading
Fresh install on Ubuntu
Page 403 Forbidden errors
Due to Messy page

I think you should modify from:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache. It should work.